# Why not $R_j + cR_i \rightarrow R_i$ for Elementary Row Operation of Replacement ? [Lay P6]

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

P6 of Linear Algebra and Its Applications, 4th Ed by David Lay says:

> Replacement: $\color{green}{kR_j + R_i \rightarrow R_i}$.

For example (from BP P435 Example 2): $\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
    -2 & 1  & 0  \\
    1  & -2 & -3 \\
\end{array} \right ]$
Then $\color{green}{(1/2)R1 + R2 \rightarrow R2}$ and subsequently $\color{green}{-R2 + R1  \rightarrow R1} $ effect 
$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
    2 & 0  & 2 \\
    0  & 1 & 2 \\
\end{array} \right ]$.

[Still, why is $\color{darkred}{R_j + cR_i \rightarrow R_i}$ wrong?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/593772/53259). Here, $R1 + 2R2 \rightarrow R2$ and subsequently $R2 - R1  \rightarrow R1 $ effect 
the same REF matrix as the above?

Pursuant to user jwsiegel's answer, would someone please explain why

> $R_j + cR_i \rightarrow R_i$ is the composition of first
>   $\frac{1}{c} R_j + R_i \rightarrow R_i$ and second
>   $cR_i \rightarrow R_i$?

I checked this for $\color{darkred}{R_1 + 2R_2 \rightarrow R_2}$ but I don't perceive the deeper reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R_j + cR_i \rightarrow R_i$ is the composition of firstly doing
$\frac{1}{c} R_j + R_i \rightarrow R_i$ and then secondly
$cR_i \rightarrow R_i$.

To see why this is so, note that you wish to replace $R_i$ by $R_j + cR_i$.
The first step replaces $R_i$ by $\frac{1}{c} R_j + R_i$. Denote the new value of $R_i$ as $R_i'$: to wit, $R_i' := \frac{1}{c} R_j + R_i$.
The second step then multiplies $R_i'$ by $c$.
So the final value of the $i$th row is $R_i'' = cR_i' = c\left(\frac{1}{c} R_j + R_i\right) = R_j + cR_i$.

So as long as $c\neq 0$, $R_j + cR_i \rightarrow R_i$ is the composition
of two elementary row operations and can thus be used to put a matrix into REF.

Comment: +1. Thank you very much. Please advise me if you mind my ancillary edit in which I elucidated the various R_is.

Answer (score 0):

The operation in your second paragraph in dark red ($\color{darkred}{R_j + cR_i \rightarrow R_i}$, or replacing $R_i$ by a copy of $R_j$ modified by a multiple of $R_i$ itself) does not ensure any trace of $R_i$ will be left in the result, unlike your first paragraph in green. The multiple might be zero, in which case one will be left with just two copies of $R_j$. For this reason this kind of replacement should not be allowed. It could be made innocuous by requiring multiplication by a *nonzero* constant, but that case can already be obtained by combining traditional row operations, so there is really no reason for the effort of introducing this kind of row operation.

The traditional row operations all have the property of being immediately and obviously reversible by the same kind of operation. For instance, your first paragraph in green (adding a multiple of $R_j$ to $R_i$) is undone by adding the opposite multiple of the unchanged $R_j$ to $R_i$); for the operation you propose this is much less the case (and only possible at all if using the zero multiple is forbidden).

Comment: +1. Thank you. Please advise me if you mind my (ancillary) edit; I just elucidated which operation you were referring to.